# get a bash's cwd

Tags: linux, bash

If I open up 2 terminals in Ubuntu, via `ps u` I can see 2 `bash`'s `pid`.

My problem is from one terminal, how can I know the `bash`'s *cwd* in the other terminal?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish here? Why do you need the PID from the other terminal.  There may be ways to solve your issue more directly.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, Sorry, but I can't even figure out one.

Comment: @Alcott: if *we* know why you need to know the current working directory of another shell, we may be able to suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check

```
/proc/<pid>/cwd
```

Comment: But how should I know the abs path of `/proc/<pid>/cwd`?

Comment: @Alcott That _is_ an absolute path, just replace `<pid>` with a valid process id. You can get the pid of the current shell from the `$$` variable. So if you have two pids, then use the one not equal to `$$`.

Answer (score 2):

The `pwdx` command prints the current working directory of each given process ID.

Example from Solaris (believe Ubuntu also has the command):-

```
$ cd /tmp
$ pwdx $$
22281:  /tmp
```